# How to color matching patterns in sed

Tags: bash, function, shell, sed, colors

G'day,

I have a log searching function like this:

```
function searchLogs() {
    local logFile="$1"
    local filters="${@:2}"
    local sedScript='/^---/ !{H;$ !d};x';

    # loop over filters and add each to sed script
    for filter in $filters
    do
       # append filter
       sedScript=$sedScript';/'$filter'/ !d';
    done;

    # search log file for log events that contain ALL filters
    sed -e "$sedScript" "$logFile";
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
$ searchLogs <file> <pattern> <pattern> | less -R
```

...and will build a command like this

```
sed -e '/^---/ !{H;$ !d};x;/<pattern>/ !d;/<pattern>/ !d' <file> | less -R
```

...but I would like it to color the matches in addition...

...however, I'm having no luck at all. Does anyone know how each match could be colored with `sed`?

p.s. I do not want to use `grep` as I'm using `grep` for a wrapper function that I pipe into that colors parts of the log files to make them easier to read e.g. (using bold to show what the `grep` command is already coloring)

**----------**

**id=** 12345

**client=** SomeService

**time=** 12:01

**----------**

Comment: If input=`12345` and patterns are `1` and `4`, are sed matches `[1234]5` or `[1]23[4]5` (using brackets to highlight the match)? What's the problem with `sed ... | grep --color=always ... | grep ...` ?

Comment: @jhnc as I said I'm piping in the whole output of that function into grep to color specific parts of the logs `searchLogs <file> <pattern> <pattern> | grep --color=always -e "^[^=]*" -e "---" -e "," | less -R` so that they are easier to read. I would like to do it with `sed` so that I can color the matches a different color.

Comment: `sed ... | GREP_COLORS=... grep --color=always ... | GREP_COLORS=... grep ...` ?

Comment: see also [multicolored grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104350/multicolored-grep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about still using grep, and set the GREP_COLORS for it locally:

```
echo ab | GREP_COLORS='ms=1;33' grep --color=always a | GREP_COLORS='ms=1;32' grep --color=always b
```